# Adding characters to a string in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I currently have a string that I want to edit by adding spaces between each character, so I currently have `s = 'abcdefg'` and I want it to become `s = 'a b c d e f g'`. Is there any easy way to do this using loops?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
>>> ' '.join('abcdefg')
'a b c d e f g'
```

Comment: Remove the unneeded spaces in your function call.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: uhh, why? Last time I checked, the usage of whitespace was a user's choice of a coding style..

Comment: Pep8 `Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations:

    - Immediately inside parentheses, brackets or braces.

      Yes: spam(ham[1], {eggs: 2})
      No:  spam( ham[ 1 ], { eggs: 2 } )`

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: PEP8 isn't a rule or something everybody has to follow, it's a guideline. If a developer wants to use a different styling for their projects (which especially makes a lot of sense when Python is not all they are doing) then that's completely fine and PEP8 should rather be ignored than blindly enforced.

Comment: But spaces inside parens are a particular weird thing. I for one have never seen it used anywhere and you'd be hard-pressed to cite any advantages. When you don't have a good reason to do otherwise, go mainstream - for the sake of the majority of programmers.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: [PEP 1](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/): *PEP Types*: "Informational PEPs do not necessarily represent a Python community consensus or recommendation, so users and implementors are free to ignore Informational PEPs or follow their advice."

Comment: @Jakob: You'll get a better reception if you suggest a style cleanup rather than flatly telling people what to do.  I don't think that was a change @Lennart should be making in other people's answers.

Comment: Personally I do. I know they are not rules but when everyone follows pep 8 you get less random crap.

Answer (score 4):

You did specify "using loops"

A string in Python is an iterable, meaning you can loop over it.

Using loops:

```
>>> s = 'abcdefg'
>>> s2=''
>>> for c in s:
...    s2+=c+' '
>>> s2
'a b c d e f g '    #note the trailing space there...
```

Using a comprehension, you can produce a list:

```
>>> [e+' ' for e in s]
['a ', 'b ', 'c ', 'd ', 'e ', 'f ', 'g ']  #note the undesired trailing space...
```

You can use `map`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.concat,s,' '*len(s))
['a ', 'b ', 'c ', 'd ', 'e ', 'f ', 'g ']
```

Then you have that pesky list instead of a string and a trailing space...

You could use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(.)',r'\1 ',s)
'a b c d e f g '
```

You can even fix the trailing space with a regex:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(.(?!$))',r'\1 ',s)
'a b c d e f g'
```

If you have a list, use `join` to produce a string:

```
>>> ''.join([e+' ' for e in s])
'a b c d e f g '
```

You can use the `string.rstrip()` string method to remove the unwanted trailing whitespace:

```
>>> ''.join([e+' ' for e in s]).rstrip()
'a b c d e f g'
```

You can even write to a memory buffer and get a string:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> fp=StringIO()
>>> for c in s:
...    st=c+' '
...    fp.write(st)
... 
>>> fp.getvalue().rstrip()
'a b c d e f g'
```

But since [join](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.join) works on lists or iterables, you might as well use join on the string:

```
>>> ' '.join('abcdefg')
'a b c d e f g'   # no trailing space, simple!
```

**The use of `join` in this way is one of the most important Python idioms.**

Use it.

There are performance considerations as well. Read [this comparison](http://skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) on various string concatenation methods in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Using f-string,

```
s = 'abcdefg'
temp = ""

for i in s:
    temp += f'{i} '
    
s = temp   
print(s)
```

```
a b c d e f g

[Program finished]
```